# QueuedDeliveryRequirements | Actual Meaning

Tags: wcf

Could someone please let me know what does QueuedDeliveryRequirements signify in DeliveryRequirements attribute?

MSDN says *"Specifies whether the binding for a service must support queued contracts."*  This confuses me further as to what is "queued contracts". Please explain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, when you define a service interface, eg:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISomethingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Something();
}
```

there are no restrictions inherent in what kind of transport binding the interface will be exposed on, and this is a good thing, as it decouples the interface developer from having to think about how the service will actually be deployed and managed in the real world.

However, there are certain situations where as the interface developer, you need to bake in a requirement for a specific sort of binding, and a good example of this would be a queued binding. In WCF, Queued bindings are those transport bindings which take advantage of the msmq platform which comes with windows.

You may have good reason for specifying this at service design time - for example you need to enforce strict in-order, exactly-once, message delivery as part of your SLA.

If so WCF allows you to use the DeliveryRequirementsAttribute to specify this:

```
[DeliveryRequirementsAttribute(
    QueuedDeliveryRequirements = QueuedDeliveryRequirementsMode.Required )] 
public class SomethingService : ISomethingService
{
    public void Something();
}
```

Hope this helps you.